# Mapbox Android Layout as Marker?

Tags: android, android-layout, mapbox

Is it possible to subclass a mapbox markers and attach a live ViewGroup instead of using a bitmap Icon?

The reason is that I need a highly animating ViewGroup that can be attached to a position.

Answer (score 0):

Mapbox is an OpenSource code and you can modify the class MarkerViewOptions() to set a ViewGroup.

The current SDK only has the option of a Builder like this:

```
mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerViewOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(-33.85699436, 151.21510684))
    .title("Sydney Opera House")
    .snippet("Bennelong Point, Sydney NSW 2000, Australia"));
```

Check [MapboxMarkers](https://www.mapbox.com/help/android-markers/) for more info.